# \r\n in C# not replaced

Tags: c#, regex

I have this string read from a table in sql:

```
 Yderligere tillidshverv:
Medlem af bestyrelsen for Dansk XXSW, region Århus.
Andre aktiviteter:
Opfinder af 123 trapper.
```

What I want to do is replace occurences of \r\n with just a single \n. However it is not working. The problem is that notepad++ still shows CRLF. It should only show LF. What am I missing? Here is my code:

```
string x = returnValue.Replace("\r\n", "\n");
```

Comment: try `string x = returnValue.Replace("\\r\\n", "\\n");`

Comment: Or `string x = returnValue.Replace(@"\r\n", @"\n");`

Comment: If `\r\n` is a literal string, then the above suggestions will work (if you plan to replace with a literal `\n`).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Oops!  Good catch.  Yeah, `string x = returnValue.Replace(@"\r\n", "\n");` is what you likely want.

Comment: Whitespace-related questions are too unclear without a code demo. Please provide one to see what exactly you have.

Comment: You clearly state CRLF to be replaced with LF. Your code works fine for me when I look at the value of x after the call. Are you sure your test is valid? You saved the output to a file, opened in Notepad++ and checked it didn't automatically change the line breaks?

Comment: I tried adding @ in the replace call but still no results. When I hover the variable in Visual Studio then I can see the \r\n characters. After replacement I can see the \r\n is replaced with \n and that is how it should be. But when I copy the variable value to Notepad++ it still shows \r\n. I for example just replace with empty string then all seems to be working...

Comment: So either the Visual Studio text viewer or notepad++ replaced the *nix Line break with the standard windows one during the display/ copy process. Your test for determining the outcome is completely invalid. The code is working as expected.

Comment: *when I copy the variable value to Notepad++* - how do you do that?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Hover the variable and click on the little arrow and click Text Visualizer. Copy all contents and then paste into notepad++.

Comment: @JamesBarrass: I Seriously doubt that because I've used this approach many times in many projects as well... Never been an issue...

Comment: If you hover over the string and it say it doesn't contain the `\r` character but by the time you visualise it copy and paste it then it does. I know which view I'd believe. Failing that. Write the string to file using something like File.WriteAllText and view it with a hex editor

Comment: You have been cheated by Notepad++. It restores the line endings to the ones that are set for the current document. I have reproduced the same behavior with Notepad2. Perhaps, that is what is happening in the clipboard. Just write the new contents to the text file using StreamWriter, and you are done.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: That was the issue! Thanks.

Comment: @JohnJackson: I posted my answer, please check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you paste a string from a Windows clipboard into Notepad++, the linebreaks get converted to the line ending style set for the current document (see the bottom of the screen).

[image]

If you right click and select UNIX, you will be able to paste the string with `\n` only. **This will also change all line endings to `LF`.**

**If you do not want to change all line endings** in the document to `LF`, you can use *EDIT* > *Paste Special* -> *Paste Binary Content*

However, from C#, you can just write the variable content into a text file:

```
var s = "I know\r\nit should\r\n";
var b = s.Replace("\r\n", "\n");
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(@"PATH_TO_FILE", false, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    sw.Write(b);
}
```

And enjoy `\n` linebreaks.

Answer (score -1):

Using the Regex class will work. I used linqpad to quickly test code which has the Dump() extension method

```
Regex.Replace("test\r\ntest","\r\n","\n").Select(x => x).Dump();
```

Update : A regular replace also works BTW. You state that it doesn't?

```
"test\r\ntest".Replace("\r\n","\n").Select(x => x).Dump();
```

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the OP problem, which is: copying the data from a Text View window and pasting into Notepad++.